# setting background image in lightning web component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have my background.png file in my staticresource folder, when I set it as an image I could be able to see that image in application, but if I set as background image ,it is not visible.why is it so?

CSS:

```
   .background_img {
    background-image: url('../../staticresources/background/background.png');
     }
```

The above given code is what I added in css.

HTML:

```
<div class="background_img">
      <div style= {backgroundUrl}>
        <h1>Salesforce project</h1>
    </div> 
</div>
```

JS:

```
 import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
 import  backgroundUrl from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/background';
 export default class Sampleapp extends LightningElement {
 get backgroundStyle() {
   return `height:50rem;background-image:url(${backgroundUrl})`;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to `import` the static resource url and then use it.

Here is example:

[image]

HTML:

```
<template>
  <div style={backgroundStyle}>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import backgroundUrl from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/background';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    get backgroundStyle() {
        return `height:50rem;background-image:url(${backgroundUrl})`;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the image in a static resource, and in the CSS file of the Lightning web component you could use the below mentioned syntax.

```css
background-image: url('/resource/static_resource_name');
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the one already posted?

Comment: @glls this is CSS, the first answer is returning a CSS string via JavaScript.

Comment: You can also use this one
background: url('/resource/ImagesFolderName/someimagename.svg') this one worked for me by putting it in lwc css file